# Brew command throwing github related error

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

all my brew commands (update, config, docker et al) are throwing below error on my Mac v10.14.2:

```
brew update
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Error: homebrew/homebrew-dupes does not exist! Run 'brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes'
homebrew/homebrew-x11 does not exist! Run 'brew untap homebrew/homebrew-x11'
```

I have already tried the below options:
 1. brew untap homebrew/homebrew-x11 -> gives the same error as reported.
 2. brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes -> gives the same error as reported.
 3. brew resintall fails with the same error as reported at `Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force`

**brew related entry in ~/.bash_profile:**
`alias brew='brew update && brew'`

Any suggestion on how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Close and reopen your terminal or try another terminal application such as iTerm.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I am using iTerm and have restarted my laptop multiple times but it hasn't resolved my problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the content of `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the standard macOS Terminal?

Comment: Yes @OrtomalaLokni. I have same problem in standard MacOS Terminal with brew.

Comment: Run `tcsh` and try `brew update` into this new shell.

Comment: That worked :) . Thanks a lot @OrtomalaLokni for your help.

Comment: Ok, but you still don't the root cause of your problem, isn't it? It should be related to one of the bash configuration file.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/ does not exist or removed so untap the current repository and then find another working git repository to update brew.

```
brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes
brew update
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like errors related to missing git repos (or *cask*) trigger the following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

It's an error triggered by `git`, hence the `git`-related prompt.

That prompt message upon failing to fetch a no longer existing repo from `git` was introduced with [this pull-request at Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-livecheck/pull/1019). The explanation for it is documented in the pull-request description.

*"Untapping"* the *cask* as prompted will get you past this error, as **Jemal Miftah** pointed out.